# TypeError: argmax(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not numpy.ndarray

Tags: nlp, gpt-2

I am traning a model GPT-2 using my curated dataset, and getting the following error. When I am trying to debug any issue, a new error comes. Can anyone helpme to fix my script so that it can run. The traing process starts but later gets many error.
I donot know how to fix these erros, but can anyone help me to fix my script? It would be very helpful.

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd
from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2ForSequenceClassification, Trainer, TrainingArguments
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

# Load the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/singleton/annotated_data.csv')
subset_df = df.head(20)

# Extract the programs and labels
programs = subset_df["program"].astype(str).tolist()
labels = subset_df["label"].tolist()

# Define the maximum input length for the model
max_input_length = 250

# Initialize the label encoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

# Encode the labels
encoded_labels = label_encoder.fit_transform(labels)

# Load the tokenizer
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

# Define the custom dataset
class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, programs, labels, tokenizer, max_length):
        self.programs = programs
        self.labels = labels
        self.tokenizer = tokenizer
        self.max_length = max_length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.programs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        program = self.programs[idx]
        label = self.labels[idx]

        encoding = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(
            program,
            add_special_tokens=True,
            max_length=self.max_length,
            padding="max_length",
            truncation=True,
            return_tensors="pt"
        )

        input_ids = encoding["input_ids"].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.long)
        attention_mask = encoding["attention_mask"].squeeze().to(dtype=torch.float)  # Convert to Float data type

        return {
            "input_ids": input_ids,
            "attention_mask": attention_mask,
            "labels": torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)
        }

# Create the dataset
dataset = CustomDataset(programs, encoded_labels, tokenizer, max_length=max_input_length)

# Split the dataset into training and evaluation subsets
train_subset_df = subset_df.head(16)
eval_subset_df = subset_df.tail(4)
train_dataset = CustomDataset(train_subset_df["program"].astype(str).tolist(),
                              label_encoder.transform(train_subset_df["label"].tolist()),
                              tokenizer, max_length=max_input_length)
eval_dataset = CustomDataset(eval_subset_df["program"].astype(str).tolist(),
                             label_encoder.transform(eval_subset_df["label"].tolist()),
                             tokenizer, max_length=max_input_length)

# Define the training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="output_directory",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=4,
    save_steps=500,
    save_total_limit=2,
    logging_steps=100,
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
)

# Initialize the model
model = GPT2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("gpt2", num_labels=len(label_encoder.classes_))
model.config.pad_token_id = model.config.eos_token_id
# Modify model output to be Float
model.config.return_dict = False
model = model.float()

# Define the data preprocessing function
def preprocess_function(examples):
    input_ids = torch.stack([example["input_ids"] for example in examples])
    attention_mask = torch.stack([example["attention_mask"] for example in examples])
    labels = torch.tensor([example["labels"] for example in examples], dtype=torch.float)  # Change label dtype to float

    return {
        "input_ids": input_ids,
        "attention_mask": attention_mask,
        "labels": labels
    }

# Create the Trainer for fine-tuning
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=eval_dataset,
    data_collator=preprocess_function
)

# Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()

# Evaluate the fine-tuned model
eval_results = trainer.evaluate()

# Compute predicted labels
eval_predictions = trainer.predict(eval_dataset)
predicted_labels = torch.argmax(eval_predictions.predictions[0], dim=1)
# Reshape predictions
predictions_array = np.array(eval_predictions.predictions)
# Reshape predictions
reshaped_predictions = predictions_array.reshape(-1, predictions_array.shape[-1])
# Apply argmax along axis=0
predicted_labels = np.argmax(reshaped_predictions, axis=1).astype(np.float32)  # Convert predicted labels to float32
#print(eval_predictions.predictions.shape)
print("Shape of eval_predictions.predictions:", eval_predictions.predictions.shape)
# Convert the encoded labels back to original labels
decoded_labels = label_encoder.inverse_transform(predicted_labels.cpu().numpy())
# Convert the encoded labels for eval_dataset back to original labels
decoded_eval_labels = label_encoder.inverse_transform(eval_labels)
# Compute evaluation metrics
precision = precision_score(decoded_eval_labels, decoded_labels)
recall = recall_score(decoded_eval_labels, decoded_labels)
f1 = f1_score(decoded_eval_labels, decoded_labels)
# Print the evaluation metrics
print("Precision:", precision)
print("Recall:", recall)
print("F1-Score:", f1)

# Plot the performance measures
labels = ["Precision", "Recall", "F1-Score"]
values = [precision, recall, f1]

plt.bar(labels, values)
plt.xlabel("Performance Measure")
plt.ylabel("Value")
plt.title("Model Performance")
plt.show()

# Save the fine-tuned model
trainer.save_model("output_directory")

# Load the fine-tuned model
model = GPT2ForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("output_directory")
model.eval()

# Maximum input length for tokenization
max_input_length = 250

def predict(program):
    encoded_input = tokenizer(program, truncation=True, padding=True, max_length=max_input_length, return_tensors='pt')
    input_ids = encoded_input['input_ids']
    attention_mask = encoded_input['attention_mask']

    # Make the prediction
    with torch.no_grad():
        logits = model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)

    # Convert logits to float data type
    logits_float = logits[0].float()

    # Apply softmax to obtain probabilities
    probabilities = F.softmax(logits_float, dim=1).squeeze().tolist()

    # Get the predicted label and score
    score = max(probabilities)

    # Return the prediction
    return {'label': predicted_label, 'score': score}
#print(eval_predictions.predictions.shape)
# Example usage:
program_text = "Your program text here"
prediction = predict(program_text)
print("Prediction:", prediction)
```